# Loop through items and place in correct list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of products which have two columns: `Name` and `Category`.

How can I loop through each product in `@products` and place them in list-groups with the same `product.category`?

### Current Code:

This creates a new `list-group` for each product. I'd like to group the products with same categories together.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-md-6 column_container">    
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success active">
          <%= product.category %>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <%= product.name %>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

### For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 column_container">    
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success active">
          Category Name                                 <---- category
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          Product1 Name                                 <---- has same category
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          Product1 Name                                 <---- has same category
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 column_container">    
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success active">
          Category Name                                 <---- category
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          Product1 Name                                 <---- has same category
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          Product1 Name                                 <---- has same category
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should I be using two loops? One to loop through each category, then another nested loop to place each product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group_by` method:

```
<% @products.group_by(&:category).each do |category, products| %>
  # do something with category

  <% products.each do |product| %>
    # do something with each product
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

You wanna sort the different categories by alphabetical order? Okay!

```
<% @products.group_by(&:category).sort_by{ |category, products| category.to_s }.each do |category, products| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry for the newb question, what do you mean "sort the different categories?" for the second code.

Comment: sort by alphabetical order, sorry I should have written this. I will add it now